# Does ConstBitStream load the entire file to the memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bitstream

Does `ConsBitStream` load the entire file to the memory when using is as follows?

```
s = ConstBitStream(filename='test/test.m1v')
```

I am performing bit operation on large files and I want to avoid loading them entirely.

Comment: Does this refer to the `bitstring` third-party module? https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/constbitstream.html

Comment: @akx yes, that's right